# Pin tool and itrace

Tags: c++, intel, objdump

Hello i run the pin toll itrace.cpp file to get the trace of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pin.H"

FILE * trace;

// This function is called before every instruction is executed
// and prints the IP
VOID printip(VOID *ip) { fprintf(trace, "%p\n", ip); }

// Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    // Insert a call to printip before every instruction, and pass it the IP
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)printip, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_END);
}

// This function is called when the application exits
VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    fprintf(trace, "#eof\n");
    fclose(trace);
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    PIN_ERROR("This Pintool prints the IPs of every instruction executed\n" 
          + KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() + "\n");
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    trace = fopen("itrace.out", "w");

    // Initialize pin
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    // Register Instruction to be called to instrument instructions
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);

    // Register Fini to be called when the application exits
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Start the program, never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

And i have the following traces:

This is a sample :

```
0x40001e90
0x40001e91
0x40001ee4
0x40001ee5
```

How i can find in which command each of this trace belongs to?
I used objdump -S myfile but i cant find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find IP in a program using

```
objdump -S exe > exe.asm
```

Search **40001e90** instead of 0x40001e90

Answer (score 3):

You should use the "INS_Disassemble (INS ins)" function as listed in the [API](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#g3f20e37497b0ed02b03ca709a0ae42d1)

Something like the following would do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pin.H"

FILE * trace;

// This function is called before every instruction is executed
// and prints the IP
VOID printip(VOID *ip, const string *s) { fprintf(trace, "%p --> %s\n", ip, s->c_str()); }

// Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    string instrString = INS_Disassemble(ins); 
    // Insert a call to printip before every instruction, and pass it the IP
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, 
                  (AFUNPTR)printip, 
                  IARG_INST_PTR, 
                  IARG_PTR, new string(instrString),
                  IARG_END);
}

// This function is called when the application exits
VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    fprintf(trace, "#eof\n");
    fclose(trace);
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    PIN_ERROR("This Pintool prints the IPs of every instruction executed\n" 
          + KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() + "\n");
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    trace = fopen("itrace.out", "w");

    // Initialize pin
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    // Register Instruction to be called to instrument instructions
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);

    // Register Fini to be called when the application exits
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Start the program, never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```