# How do I determine the initial register values being utilized in Intel x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I am working on counting the number of assembly instructions in a disassembled code (add,sub,jmp, etc.). I also have to consider conditions that might cause loops/jumps requiring me to repeatedly count a set of instructions. Therefore, I have to record the values of registers, so when I encounter a condition like "jne", I'll know whether the code jumped or if I can just continue parsing the disassembled code.

I am currently confused on the initial values of registers like (edx, eax, rbp, rsp, etc.). I used **objdump** to dump all the assembly code, and I can see that in my disassembled `<main>` function, the first line of assembly code is:

```
push rbp

mov rbp, rsp

sub rsp, 0xdb0
```

I have no idea where rbp is initialized. When I did a control F for "rbp", I see the first thing that pops up is the "rex.WRX push rbp" instruction. Does this initialize rbp to 0?

I am also confused on where the assembly code starts from. I originally thought it started from `<main>`, but I also see other functions like `<start>` and `<init>`.

Any clarifications would be appreciated!

Comment: If you need a dynamic instruction count, you have to run (or simulate) the code in some kind of emulator.  Static disassembly is not particularly useful, except in trivial cases of simple flow control.  `push` *reads* RBP, it doesn't modify it; it's saving the caller's value of RBP to restore before returning, because it's a call-preserved register.  `mov rbp, rsp` copies the stack pointer to the frame pointer, giving it a value for the duration of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Are you saying I won't have access to some register values/address values being addressed because it is static disassembly? I have to use objdump, but if I am not able to record register values for checking conditions like 
"je" and "jne", that's fine.

Comment: x86 assembly is Turing complete.  Counting instructions without just simulating it is, in the general case, of equal difficulty to solving the halting problem.  (Which is provably unsolvable for at least some programs, for any given attempt at writing an analyzer.)  Many loop branches *are* something like `dec ecx` / `jnz .top_of_loop`, and if that came from a function arg then you have no idea how many trips through the loop execute.  Some loops have more variable exit conditions, like reaching the end of a linked list.  Or iterating the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: I am afraid I am still not following you though. I was planning to manually keep track of the variables myself, but that's impossible if I do not know the initial values. Correct me if I am wrong, but are you saying that if the program tries to read a value from a specific memory address, I wouldn't be able to know what that value is since that would be determined at runtime? I also read that special registers get loaded at runtime, so their values are not known from just the assembly, and that there are instructions that automatically update these values without showing the value in code.

Comment: So you are planning to write an x86 simulator.  I guess you could do that based on asm text, instead of machine code, but a complete executable has everything where it's needed for you to simulate it already.  You'd need to kind of "assemble" the disassembly it back into code with addresses, and getting static data from disassembly is also clunky.  If the program is C++ with exceptions, you're screwed: jumps will depend on `.eh_frame` metadata.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out.Is there enough info from the disassembled code alone to be able to track the initial values, and the instructions applied on these values to modify them.Simple stuff like loading a register with 1 and adding/subtracting are easy to find.My concern is if there are registers/instructions that update values that doesn't show in the assembly code? I also have commands like "call d50 <fprintf@plt> " but I don't see "d50" as a subroutine anywhere. I just want to know if it's even possible without simulating it.Otherwise,I'll just iterate through it vertically.

Comment: No, the initial values of some registers are function args.  Unless you start tracking at `_start`, in which case all registers potentially hold garbage so the code there won't depend on those values.  (Except the stack pointer, which points at the stack, and one other register that holds a pointer to a callback function from the dynamic linker.  argc and argv are on the stack, in the x86-64 System V ABI.  But the absolute address of the stack isn't something code will depend on)

Comment: `d50` is an address (relative to the start of the text section in this file, because either this is an unlinked `.o`, or it's a PIE executable).

Comment: I disassembled the whole thing, and I found the d50 subroutine.  Can you explain more about function args stopping me from knowing how many times something might loop? I am writing a python script to count the number of instructions executed. I can start at "_start", but my main concern if if something tries to access a value at a specific address because then I'm not sure how to find that value?

Comment: Consider a function like `strlen` which loops until it gets to the end of the string.  The string was passed as a function arg.  Different calls to strlen, with different strings, will run through the loop a different number of times.

Comment: Yes, I am disassembling a C program that definitely has a lot of function args. So there's no way to see the function args of a subroutine? Don't those function args have to be written somewhere?  If that's the case, I will just have to iterate through the assembly code and ignore any loops.

Comment: Yes, the caller will put the first up-to-6 integer/pointer args in registers before a `call`.  (Assuming the calling convention from the x86-64 System V ABI, all non-Windows OSes).  But anything passed by reference will be just passing a pointer to data in memory that the function will dereference, so again for the strlen case, the loop trip count will depend on memory, not just registers.  Most programs have loops that depend on memory contents, so you'll need to simulate memory as well as regs for most programs.

Comment: So to be clear, if I don't simulate the code, I won't see the value at that memory location which means I won't know how long something looped? This would also apply to any instruction that loads  a value at a memory address into a register?

Comment: Yes, that's a good summary.  Most branches involve a value that was at some point stored in memory; only a few loops just only registers with values that came from immediate operands like `mov ecx, 100`.

Answer (score 4):

Objdump will give you only static disassembly of an executable. To get the run time trace of your program you can use tools like [Intel Pin](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads.html). There is an itrace.so tool in ManualExample folder of pin distributions that you can simply use to get the run time trace of a program.

**Path-to-pin-folder/pin -t pin-tool-name-with-path -- binary-to-instrument**

Pin framework also let you to log content of different registers and content and address of program variables. See [PIN manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98253/Pin/html/index.html) for examples and how to write your own tools. You can always modify the content of an existing example to modify it for your needs. To write a completely new pin tool, you should use the pin tool template in *MyPinTool* directory.

"push rbp and other instructions at start of a function". During a program execution **a series of functions** are called. Every function shares the registers and stack. Every function uses a portion of stack for its local variables. When a function releases the stack location are free to be used by other subsequent functions. Freeing the memory is simple, modify the stack top (rbp) value. Using a stack ensures that same set of memory locations can be used by local variables of many functions, reducing memory requirement.

main() is the first **user written** function that is called during execution of a program. A set of **additional functions** which are not part of the original program, __start(), __fini, and likes are also there as part of a program executable which are **usually not defined by users**. They are OS specific and are added by the compilers. Some of them are called before and some after the execution of user program, for initialization and house keeping.

Comment: Thanks for the response! By static disassembly, you mean I won't have access to some of the variable values/addresses being loaded? I was thinking about manually recording them as I read each instruction, but the problem is that I don't have base values to start with. Does Intel Pin give me assembly code? I downloaded it and got it to compile, but I am not sure how to run it. I see the itrace.so file, but how do I use it?

Comment: `push rbp` doesn't "preserve the stack".  It saves RBP *onto* the stack.  RBP is being used as a frame pointer in this function, but that's optional (the default for un-optimized code, though).

Comment: It's a big simplification to say "the OS" executes both `_start` and `main`.  Really the OS only executes `_start`.  It's `_start` that (eventually) calls `main`.  You can write your own custom `_start` if you want, and if you don't call main from it, nothing will.  You could argue that the CRT start code containing `_start` is part of the OS, but just to be clear it's *not* part of the kernel.

Comment: I got PIN to run, but the itrace.out file is just a bunch of hex numbers like "0x7f210836eeaa". Do you know how to get the assembly instructions instead?

Comment: kindly look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955630/pin-tool-and-itrace.

Comment: Thanks, this helped!